# Equivalence of equations

Tags: trigonometry

$
\sin ^2 \alpha =  \frac{\tan ^2 \alpha}{1+\tan^2 \alpha}
$

$
1+\tan^2 \alpha =  \frac{\tan ^2 \alpha}{\sin ^2 \alpha}
$

It is said that these two equations are equivalent. How can that be? I know that for two equations to be equivalent they must have the same set of solutions. But here the first one has solutions for all angles except $\alpha \neq \frac{\pi}{2}+ k\pi $ and the second for all angles except $\alpha \neq k \times \frac{\pi}{2}$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. May someone give an elaboration?

Edit:

From wikipedia: "Two equations or two systems of equations are equivalent if they have the same set of solutions."
And: "Multiplying or dividing both sides of an equation by a non-zero constant transforms an equation or a system into an equivalent one".

How dividing by $\sin ^2 \alpha$ leads to an equivalent to the first one? It changes the the set of possible solutions to the equation and this means that by definition these two equations are not equivalent. I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever two equations are said to be equivalent, it is worth exploring the process of going from one equation to another. In this case, we can consider performing the following sequence of operations on the first equation:

1. Divide both sides of the first equation by $ \sin^2\alpha $.
2. Multiply both sides of the resulting equation with $ 1 + \tan^2\alpha $

At this point, it is worth noting that the first step is only allowed when $ \sin^2\alpha \neq 0 $.

Therefore, the first equation is only equivalent to the second when $ \sin^2\alpha \neq 0 $. When this is not true, the case must be considered separately.

Comment: So when the sine is zero they are not equivalent right? See my edit also :)

Comment: Right :) Understanding of such situations is critical when studying limits and continuity. A similar, but simpler conundrum would be: whether $\frac{x^2}{x} = x$? ...well... yes, but only when $x \neq 0$

Comment: So when we make a transformation to an equation in order to compare the new one and the previous we need to compare to the domain of the last one right? What with f(x) = (x-1)/(x-1) = g(x) = 1. They say these are also equivalent functions.

Comment: Absolutely... It's all about the domains. So the functions are equal if the domain of definition is $ \mathbb{R}-\{1\} $, but are not equal if the domain of definition is $ \mathbb{R} $. These subtleties are hidden everywhere. For instance in your original question: is the first equation even true? The LHS is defined for all $\mathbb{R}$ but the RHS is not defined whenever $ \tan x $ is not defined.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_%28mathematics%29 I think this answers my question too.

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply the second equation by $$\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{1 + \tan^2 \alpha}$$ you have the first equation. Since $\tan^2 \alpha\geq 0$, this multiplication gives us no need to exclude any solutions that aren't excluded in original equation.

The second equation does have $\sin^2\alpha$ in the denominator, so we need to rule out, from the solution set of the second equation, those alpha where $\sin\alpha = 0$, which are integer multiples of $\pi$.

So the identities are equivalent **except** at the values $\alpha = k\pi, k \in \mathbb Z$.

For **both** equations, we need to omit those values such that $\cos \alpha = 0$ which would occur at all integer multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}+ k\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
1+\tan^2 \alpha = \sec^2 \alpha\implies\\
 \frac{\tan^2 \alpha}{\sec^2\alpha} = \frac{\sin^2 \alpha}{\cos^2\alpha} \frac{1}{1/cos^2\alpha}  = \sin^2\alpha \frac{\cos^2\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha} = \sin^2\alpha
$$
to get the first identity
$$
\sin^2\alpha + \cos^2\alpha = 1 
$$
divide by $\cos^2\alpha$ leads to
$$
\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha} + 1 = \tan^2\alpha + 1 = \frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\tan^2a}{1+\tan^2a}=\frac{\frac{\sin^2a}{\cos^2a}}{1+\frac{\sin^2a}{\cos^2a}}=\frac{\sin^2a}{\cos^2a+\sin^2a}=\sin^2a$$

So the first one is true.

$$\frac{\tan^2a}{\sin^2a}=\frac{\frac{\sin^2a}{\cos^2a}}{\sin^2a}=\frac1{\cos^2a}=\frac{\cos^2+\sin^2a}{\cos^2a}=1+\tan^2a$$

and the second one is also true.

What does these two **identities** (not equations!) "being equivalent" mean is beyond my understanding.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I mean how can the two equations be equivalent? They have different set of solutions. In the first one the sine can be zero in the second not.

Comment: First, the use of $\;\alpha\;$ is unsual for equations and l pretty usual for identities. Second, these two **are indentities**, which mean they're true for **any** value of $\;\alpha\;$ for which both sides in each are defined. Now, if you *insist* in calling them "equations" then true: the set of solutions in (2) (i.e., all $\;\alpha\neq2k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ is different from the set of solutions in (1), which is **all** $\;\alpha\;$ . Either there's a mistake in the question's name, or else this is a tricky, but good, question.